# Remote build in ionic pro fails - @ngx-translate

Tags: git, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am having problems with my remote Ionic Pro build. (Everything works fine locally.)

According to:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

the remote Ionic build is now using Angular 4.4.3. However, when I do my remote build with

> git push ionic master

I get the error:

```
[12:18:08]  typescript: node_modules/@ngx-translate/http-loader/src/http-loader.d.ts, line: 1 
            Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'. 

       L1:  import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
       L2:  import { TranslateLoader } from "@ngx-translate/core";

[12:18:08]  typescript: src/app/app.module.ts, line: 3 
            Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'. 

       L2:  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
       L3:  import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
       L4:  import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Do I just have to roll back to Angular 4.1.1? If so, and if the ionic-team/ionic/CHANGELOG.md is lying to me, how can I know what version of the libs to use with a remote build?? Has anyone else successfully moved to Ionic and Angular 4.4.3?

Comment: I've also run into this issue, except with a JSONPath library that's in my package.json file. Did you get this issue resolved?

Comment: I have an open ticket with Ionic support and they have not resolved the problem. If we use the the version of Angular etc they specify in the CHANGELOG.MD file, completely wipe out our node_modules, do a clean npm install and it works locally, it should work on their server. I think that they are modifying what package version they are actually getting before they build. I'll post something when it is resolved.

Comment: I also raised a support ticket (along with several others) for the issue, I'll also update you if I hear anything back.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, some file is still referencing @angular/http. I grep'ed through my node_modules files, found all of the references and updated/removed all of them with the exception of @ionic/app-scripts. Then *delete package-lock.json* I think it was the obsolete reference in there that was killing me.

Then, I completely deleted node_modules, restored them all with npm i, committed my changes to github, and then finally did another git push ionic master and the build succeeded. Hope this helps